# How do I declare then use a variable within a CDATA block?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, dynamics-ax-2009

I have an XSL/XML/JS file. It was written by someone who is not working here any more, and I normally only deal with SQL, so Im at a loss as to how to achieve what I need to do

Im trying to add some variables into the file within the existing CDATA block. I then use the variables within a function. However, I have tried the below and variations of this, but keep getting a syntax error within the application (Dynamics AX). Am I doing something obviously wrong here, with either how I am declaring the variables or how I am using them? These are the only changes I have made, and without these changes there are no syntax or any other issues/errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:mxm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/MxmServInterfaceOutboundAif" 
xmlns:data="http://www.example.com/data" exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi xsl">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />   
    <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="data">    
        <![CDATA[      
      
      //Minor Repairs email address  
      var MinorsEmail = xxx@domain.com
      //Service Dept email address
      var ServiceEmail = yyy@domain.com
      //Major Repairs email address  
      var MajorsEmail = zzz@domain.com

//Select appropriate email to use
function EmailFrom(fault)
      {
        var type = fault.substr(0,2);
        if (type == "MI")
          {
          var ret = MinorsEmail;
          }
        else 
          {
          var ret = concat(ServiceEmail, "; ",MajorsEmail);
          }
        return ret; 
      }
```

Edit: Adding quotes around the variable values has solved part of the problem. The problem now is that the CONCAT does not function as intended. I get the following error now:

```
Variable concat has not been declared
```

Comment: Maybe quote your string values if those email addresses are supposed to be JavaScript strings.

Comment: Could you [edit] to question to add information how this xml file is consumed in Dynamics AX? I'm surprised why the file as is produces no issues, because the code in the CDATA block is not valid [tag:x++] code and I'm not aware how AX 2009 is supposed to execute Java Script (or is it JScript?) code.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen adding quotes to the string values has resolved part of the problem. The only issue I have now is in the function. If the ELSE applies, then the CONCAT is not working - I get an error 'Variable concat has not been declared'. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @FH-Inway you can add XSL transformations in Basic - Setup - Application Integration Framework - XSLT repository. Is that what you mean?

Comment: String concatenation in JavaScript is done with the `+` operator `ServiceEmail + "; " + MajorsEmail`

Comment: Brill! Thanks @MartinHonnen

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Martin Honnen, the answer was to add quote to variable values, and to use + instead of CONCAT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:mxm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/MxmServInterfaceOutboundAif" 
xmlns:data="http://www.example.com/data" exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi xsl">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />   
    <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="data">    
        <![CDATA[      
      
      //Minor Repairs email address  
      var MinorsEmail = "xxx@domain.com"
      //Service Dept email address
      var ServiceEmail = "yyy@domain.com"
      //Major Repairs email address  
      var MajorsEmail = "zzz@domain.com"

//Select appropriate email to use
function EmailFrom(fault)
      {
        var type = fault.substr(0,2);
        if (type == "MI")
          {
          var ret = MinorsEmail;
          }
        else 
          {
          var ret = ServiceEmail + "; " + MajorsEmail;
          }
        return ret; 
      }
```